# Group 2 objects into 1 object and merge the keys

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to group 2 objects in my MongoDB documents into a single object with the keys merged. What I have is:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("..."),
  "object_a": { "keyA": 1, "keyB": "valueB" }
  "object_b": { "keyC": 2 }
}
```

And what I try to get is the following:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("..."),
  "object_a": { "keyA": 1, "keyB": "valueB", "keyC": 2 }
}
```

- I can assert that there is no key conflict
- I don't know the key names in advance

I tried with the `$addFields` operator but this will nest `object_b` inside `object_a`, not merge the keys.

```
{
  "$addFields":
  {
    "object_a": "$object_b"
  }
}
```

In other words, I am looking for a `$setUnion` but for objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/#exp._S_mergeObjects) in 3.6.

```
{"$addFields":{"object_a": {"$mergeObjects": ["$object_a", "$object_b"]}}}
```

For 3.4 you can use [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) and [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) to merge keys.

```
{"$addFields":{"object_a": { "$arrayToObject": {"$setUnion": [{"$objectToArray": "$object_a"},{"$objectToArray": "$object_b"}]}}}}
```

Comment: Flawless answer. And with `$ifNull` I can completely reproduce a `$mergeObjects` operation in MongoDB 3.4 for null handling. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an improved version for Mongo 3.4.4+ that handles null values. It is based on the solution provided by @Veeram

```
function $mergeObjects(...items) {
  return {
    $arrayToObject: {
      $setUnion: items.map(_ => (
        {$filter: {input: {$objectToArray: _}, cond: {$ne: ["$$this.v", null]}}}
      ))
    }
  }
}
```